# how can i delete special characters in a url with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to delete the following characters from a url `":" "." "\" "/"`
how can i do this in javascript?

```
original: https://www.sito.it/ricette-cat.html
convert: https-www-sito-it-ricette-cat-html
```

thanks

Comment: Your question asks about deleting chars but the expected result is for them to have been replaced with dashes, which is it? This is also covered in a lot of SO questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = 'https://www.sito.it/ricette-cat.html'
console.log(str.replace(/[^\w]+/ig,'-'))
```

Comment: thank you very much! 
Thanks so much! I'm a beginner with programming, what do these symbols do ?  / [^ \ w] + / ig?

Comment: `^ -> is negation` , `\w (word character) matches any single letter, number or underscore`, and enclosing them within [] with + match one or more characters. If you found that useful, make sure to upvote.